# How to deploy cdk image asset to ecs cluster

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy a docker image created with cdk to an ecs cluster (ec2 not fargate).

I have tried the following in typescript (with appropriate imports of course)

```
    const vpc = new ec2.VpcNetwork(this, "MyVPC", { maxAZs: 3 });

    const cluster: ecs.Cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "ecs-cluster", {
      clusterName: "demo",
      vpc: vpc
    });

    cluster.addCapacity("MyEC2Capacity", {
      instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType("t2.micro"),
      desiredCapacity: 1
    });
    const image = new ecs.AssetImage(this, "image", {directory: "client"})

    const nameService = new ecs.LoadBalancedEc2Service (this, 'name-service', {
      cluster: cluster,
      desiredCount: 1,
      image: image,
      memoryLimitMiB: 128,
      containerPort: 3000
   });
```

However when I run `cdk diff` I get the following error

```
Stack cdkTest
The cdkTest stack uses assets, which are currently not accounted for in the diff output! See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/395
IAM Statement Changes
Column width must be greater than 0.
npm verb lifecycle stack@0.1.0~cdk: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle stack@0.1.0~cdk: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/circleci/repo/stack/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
npm verb lifecycle stack@0.1.0~cdk: CWD: /home/circleci/repo/stack
npm info lifecycle stack@0.1.0~cdk: Failed to exec cdk script
npm verb stack Error: stack@0.1.0 cdk: `cdk "diff"`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
npm verb pkgid stack@0.1.0
npm verb cwd /home/circleci/repo/stack
npm verb Linux 4.4.0-141-generic
npm verb argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "cdk" "diff" "--verbose"
npm verb node v11.9.0
npm verb npm  v6.5.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! stack@0.1.0 cdk: `cdk "diff"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the stack@0.1.0 cdk script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 1578ms

Exited with code 1
```

Is it possible to get cdk to build the image and deploy to ecs?

If so how? I couldn't find any examples either on google, on aws-cdk github repo, or on the aws-cdk docs.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: So after some investigation I have identified this with being caused by a combination of using CICD and an npm library called tables.  
Tables gets the terminal width using `process.stdout.columns` which, in the CI system I am using, apparently is 0. So the library throws an exception.
I have raised a [bug issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/2253) with aws-cdk detailing this so hopefully will get an answer/resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue and so posting here for others.

The issue is caused by the CI I am using. Node thinks that the terminal width is 0 (process.stdout.columns). This is not an issue with aws-cdk but with the library it uses to construct the table of changes and resources.

A workaround is simple, simply pipe the output of the cdk to cat or similar. So for example my CI task changes from...

`npm run cdk deploy`
to
`npm run cdk deploy | cat`